# Getting renderTable to show dates as quarters

Tags: r, shiny

In my shiny app for time series forecasting, I want to accept uploads of a single column csv file. This should be quarterly demand. Since the users may have different format for dates, I don't ask for dates in the csv, but ask for starting dates and create a sequence for the other dates. Downloading the uploaded data works perfect. But in displaying the table format, the dates are displayed as numbers. This is a known problem and I saw the discussions here: [Shiny showing numbers instead of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59565784/shiny-showing-numbers-instead-of-dates). My problem is that I want to display the date as Year quarter ("2002 Q3") and I don't know how to do it. My guess is that I need to add some format in the renderTable function and tried to search for that but could not find it. Please help.

(I also tried DT but DT was not able to display the tsibble table and it showed some text in red about a problem with year quarter)

I have created a sample dataset that can be uploaded on this app: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17OPRK0g1veCEvTZWOpQwm9lZ6sb20Ill/view?usp=sharing

UI:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Upload and Download"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h5(helpText("Enter the starting point of your data below")),
      selectInput("qrtr","Quarter",choices = c("Q1","Q2", "Q3","Q4")),
      selectInput("yrr", "Year", choices = seq(from= 1990, to = 2020, by = 1)),
      fileInput("datafile","Upload data file"),
      h5(helpText("Data should be single column csv file with a header"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      downloadButton("dldata","Download data"),
      tableOutput("content")
      )
    
  )
))
```

Server:

```
library(shiny)
library(fpp3)

shinyServer(
  function(input,output){
    getdata <- reactive({
      
      #dbz <- as.data.frame(c(1,2,3,4), colnames = "Demand")
      
      infile <- input$datafile
      if(is.null(input$datafile))
        return(NULL)      
      
      dte <- paste(input$yrr,input$qrtr)
      dte <- yearquarter(dte)
      
      db <- read.csv(infile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
      db$Quarter <- seq(from = dte, by = 1, length = nrow(db))
      db <- as_tsibble(db, index = Quarter)
      
      return(db)
    })
  
    
  output$content <- renderTable(getdata())
    
    
  output$dldata <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "data.csv",
    content = function(file){write.csv(getdata(),file, , row.names = FALSE)}
  )  
    
    
      }
)
```

Comment: It would greatly increase the chances for someone to help you if you include a sample of the data used, we don't know what are the contents of the uploaded file in the shiny app. You can use `dput()` function and copy the result from the terminal if you want to share data with others.

Comment: Thanks, I have added a link to the csv file that could be used to test this out.

Comment: No SO answer so far but this is the weekend and people may need to explain things in detail since the usual cadre of mindreaders only works on weekdays. . I'm not a regular shiny user but I tried getting something going by installing all the (many) needed packages and cut-pasting the code into first the R.app and then into Rstudio. In neither case did I get the expected webpage loaded. First I got some html code to my R console and then nothing from the second code block. You might want to put in *all* the code and *all* the menu actions needed to see the operation working.